# mysqli_real_escape_string not working properly

Tags: php

I've searched and yet nothing I find seems to work.

My problem is that when using special characters as ' the input query breaks.
Now, I tried using the mysqli_real_escape_string on my string, but this returns a blank value.
I read that the mysqli_real_escape_string should be placed AFTER the database connection, and as far as I know, that is what I have done, yet it returns blank values.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

session_start();


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require_once 'connect.php';

    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $article = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['article']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO Articles
                (Title, content)
                VALUES 
                ('$title', '$article')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die('could not query database');

    $_SESSION['artcle'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['artcle'] = $title;


    mysqli_close($connect);
    header('Location: CENSORED');
}
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($query);` + show `mysql_error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot your resource parameter:

```
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['title']);
```

[PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: You're my hero. Yeah that worked, I guess I should get some sleep now (03:11)

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
$title = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
```